# Create json list from Map based on interface in Angular 9

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular9

I use `countries-map` plugin to have a map with data value.
This plugin provide this data example

```
mapData: CountriesData = {
  'ES': { 'value': 416 },
  'GB': { 'value': 94},
  'FR': { 'value': 255 }
};
```

based on these interfaces

```
interface CountriesData {
  [countryCode: string]: CountryData;
}
interface CountryData {
  value: number;
  extra?: CountryExtraData;
}
interface CountryExtraData {
  [key: string]: number |string;
}
```

My API return a map

```
{
  "countryInstallHistory": {
    "DZ": 1,
    "SN": 3
  }
}
```

In my angular project, i'm able to loop over my country list.

```
for (let [key, result] of Object.entries(this.apkHistorDto.countryInstallHistory)) {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(result)
}
```

How could I create with data sent by my API a list like this based on the interface ?

```
mapData: CountriesData = {
  'DZ': { 'value': 1},
  'SN': { 'value': 3}
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use `reduce` function of array to achieve this. See below demo

```js
let response = {
  countryInstallHistory: {
    DZ: 1,
    SN: 3,
  },
};
   
 const mapData = Object.entries(response.countryInstallHistory).reduce(
    (prev, [key, value]) => ({...prev, [key]: { value }}), {}
  )

console.log(mapData );
```

Answer (score 0):

add a data convert function like above?

```
function convertData(data) {
  let _result = {};
  let result = data.countryInstallHistory;
  for (let key in result) {
    _result[key] = { value: result[key] };
  }
  return _result;
}

let result = {
  countryInstallHistory: {
    DZ: 1,
    SN: 3,
  },
};
console.log(convertData(result));
```